# Formating x tabs to include an additional grouping variable

Tags: r

I need help creating cumulative species curves in R. I am using the iNext package

I want cumulative number of bird species on my x axis, by cumulative number of OTU reads. I then need this grouped by bird guild, so as not to have 55 species individual lines. By grouping by guild, I can 4 lines.
The probelm is that when I create a matrix for the species curve, I cant have an additional grouping varialbe... so I am not sure how to achieve this.

here is the code I have so far. Any ideas on how to achieve what I need?

1)Row.1 is the total number of OTU reads for a particular Otu in each sample

2)Label is the OTU ID

3)Species is my bird species

4)Guild is my bird categories

```
bird_matrix4 <- xtabs(Row.1~ Label + Guild+Species, data = bird)
bird_matrix4<-as.data.frame.matrix(bird_matrix4)

bird_curves_rare4<-iNEXT(bird_matrix4, q=0, datatype="abundance")
bird_curves_rare4$iNextEst
```

How do I modify xtabs so I can fit in my other grouping variable? As of now, I get an error saying "incorrect number of dimesions"

Comment: look at `ftable` function. Not able to receive help as you have not provided a reproducible example. Perharps start here https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example